# Bluetooth in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: 11.04, bluetooth

How can I use Bluetooth in Ubuntu 11.04?

When I opened Bluetooth preferences ,I get a message like"No Bluetooth adapters present" and also It gives me

> Your computer does not have any Bluetooth adapters plugged in

If I click "Receive files" option, I get "Personal File Sharing Preferences" dialog box. In that I get the following...

> This feature cannot be enabled because the required packages are not installed on your system

Also I have "Share files over the Network" option locked.

Can anyone suggest a way to get the required packages?

Comment: What bluetooth adapter do you have? Open a terminal and type `lspci` or `lsusb` and look for relevant bluetooth adapters in your system. If possible copy and paste the lines in to your question.

Comment: The packages won't help you if you have no bluetooth device, as the error messages suggest. Does your computer have built-in bluetooth (and you have it enabled in the Bios), or do you at least have a bluetooth stick attached? Otherwise installing bluetooth packages makes no sense.

Comment: What kind of system is it?  Specs please.

Comment: I tried lsusb, I got the following                             **Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub**

Comment: I also tried lspci, I got the following                               **00:00.0 Host bridge: ATI Technologies Inc Radeon Xpress 200 Host Bridge (rev 01)**
**00:01.0 PCI bridge: ATI Technologies Inc RS480 PCI Bridge**
**00:11.0 IDE interface: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB400 Serial ATA Controller (rev 80)**
**00:12.0 IDE interface: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB400 Serial ATA Controller (rev 80)**
**00:13.0 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB400 USB Host Controller (rev 80)**
**00:13.1 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB400 USB Host Controller (rev 80)**

Comment: Also I got the following                                         **00:13.2 USB Controller: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB400 USB2 Host Controller (rev 80)
00:14.0 SMBus: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB400 SMBus Controller (rev 82)
00:14.1 IDE interface: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB400 IDE Controller (rev 80)
00:14.2 Audio device: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB4x0 High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB400 PCI-ISA Bridge (rev 80)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB400 PCI-PCI Bridge (rev 80)**

Comment: The remaining is as follows                                       **01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc RC410 [Radeon Xpress 200]
02:02.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ (rev 10)**

Comment: @izzy              I donot have a bluetooth stick

Comment: @theja: Well, if you have no bluetooth (and no, according to your recent comments, you do not have it) -- what do you hope to achieve by installing bluetooth software? Another hint: Instead of multiple comments with the debug output, you can post the latter on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) or [Ubuntu Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and just put the resulting link into the comment. Makes it better readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the information you provided, the answer is: Buy a bluetooth stick and attach it to your computer -- the software is already installed ;)